# Is there a generic name for matrices of the type $kI+M_{n\times n}$, where $M^T=-M$ and $k\in R$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I know there is nothing intellectual about this question, but I need work out some properties of such matrices. I want to know if this category of matrices has some well established properties. I am not sure what to look for.

In case you have/know of some resources that discuss some properties of such matrices, it would be great help.

Comment: Related, though without any answers http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/807060/term-for-a-sum-of-diagonal-and-skew-symmetric-matrix.|
Possibly related http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/952233/eigenvalues-of-the-sum-of-a-diagonal-matrix-and-a-skew-symmetric-matrix

Comment: If $k=1$, then a matrix of your type is called a *skew type* matrix. If $k$ is not zero, then you can get a skew type matrix from your type by dividing by $k.$

Answer (score 2):

There is no generic name, except saying that it is a scalar multiple of the identity plus a skew-symmetric matrix. The determinants of such matrices have a nice formula. For example,
$$
\det\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ -b & a \end{pmatrix}=a^2+b^2,
$$

$$
\det \begin{pmatrix} a & b & c \\ -b & a & d \\ -c & -d & a\end{pmatrix}=a(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2).
$$

Can you find the general formula ?

Comment: Interesting!  Any hints towards that general formula?